# SQLAlchemy KeyError when using both an index and a UniqueConstraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I include both a `UniqueConstraint` and `Index` in my table definition I get a KeyError. However, the error goes away if I specify `UniqueConstraint` alone or `Index` alone. I'm using `SQLAlchemy==1.3.8`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.schema import Index, UniqueConstraint

Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column(String(32))
    b = Column(String(32))

UniqueConstraint('a_unique_constraint', A.a, A.b)
Index('a_index', A.a, A.b)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/ryan.zotti/Documents/repos/recommendations/orm_example.py", line 14, in 
>       UniqueConstraint('a_unique_constraint', A.a, A.b)
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2870, in **init**
>       self, *columns, _autoattach=_autoattach, _column_flag=_column_flag
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2762, in **init**
>       self._check_attach()
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2818, in _check_attach
>       self._set_parent_with_dispatch(tables.pop())
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 456, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
>       self._set_parent(parent)
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2881, in _set_parent
>       ColumnCollectionMixin._set_parent(self, table)
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2838, in _set_parent
>       for col in self._col_expressions(table):
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2834, in _col_expressions
>       for col in self._pending_colargs
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2834, in 
>       for col in self._pending_colargs
>     File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 194, in **getitem**
>       return self._data[key]
>   KeyError: 'a_unique_constraint'

Comment: The order of your arguments to `UniqueConstraint` is incorrect. Pass the columns first as positional args and the name as a keyword. See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint

Comment: When I do ```UniqueConstraint(A.a, A.b, name='a_unique_constraint')
Index(A.a, A.b, name='a_index')``` I get a different error: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'name'`

Comment: `Index` doesn’t have the same signature as `UniqueConstraint`, it accepts the name first as a positional arg: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Index